# Kernel panic when connect Wi-Fi direct (P2P) to other device

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I am using RTL8812AU [driver](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au).When I connect Wi-Fi directly to other devices (such as samsung phone), kernel panic occurs. Logs are attached below:

Log:

```
[  230.513996]Call trace:
[  230.516442] vsnprintf+0x69c/0x6a8
[  230.519839] snprintf+0x58/0x84
[  230.523113] dump_p2p_attr_ch_list+0x1b4/0x200 [8812au]
[  230.528461] rtw_p2p_check_frames+0x65c/0xa28 [8812au]
[  230.533701] fg80211_rtw_mgmt_tx+0x174/0x424 [8812au]
[  230.538843] cfg80211_mlme_mgmt_tx+0x1dc/0x398
[  230.543286]  nl80211_tx_mgmt+0x1e8/0x320
[  230.547207]  genl_rcv_msg+0x434/0x460
[  230.550867]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x10c/0x124
[  230.554785]  genl_rcv+0x3c/0x58
[  230.557921]  netlink_unicast+0x238/0x3ac
[  230.561839]  netlink_sendmsg+0x320/0x3bc
[  230.565760]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x24c/0x374
[  230.569679]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x124/0x170
[  230.573511]  __arm64_sys_sendmsg+0xbc/0x110
[  230.577694]  el0_svc_common+0xbc/0x1a8
[  230.581439]  do_el0_svc+0x2c/0x8c
[  230.584752]  el0_svc+0x18/0x28
[  230.587802]  el0_sync_handler+0x8c/0xf0
[  230.591635]  el0_sync+0x1a8/0x1c0
[  230.594945] ---[ end trace 06ed3f9944cdbc81 ]---
[  230.600960] Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: dump_p2p_attr_ch_list+0x200/0x200 [8812au]
```

I tried adding debug log in source code (`rtw_p2p.c`) in the `rtw_p2p_check_frames` function:
=> it can connect, but sometimes, when connect again, kernel panic still occurs.

I don't know how to fix this issue, can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: You've provided few details to what Ubuntu product & release you're using. If using a LTS release, as they are kernel stack choices you should be specific as to what you're actually running (*default kernel stack being set by your installed media, we currently don't know know what product & release you're using, Server? Desktop? etc*)